# C#: How can i store the values selected in checklistbox to an array

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, checklistbox

i want to use the multiple values selected in `checklistbox`in other functions of my programme.i am able to see the value as follows through `message box`

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

what are the various methods though which i can access these selected values and store them to an array,so i can use them in other parts of the programme?
Edit: i learned though searching that `ListItem` class it can be achieved but when i tried my visualbasic 2015 does not show such class even exist.

Comment: Quite confusing, it is easy if you could explain with an example that describe problem/issue

Comment: i am having 4 numbers in my checkedlistbox i have selected two of them .and now i want to store them in an array ,so that i can use them as input in my other function.@HariPrasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use it in other parts of program, make arrayList global (as un-lucky suggested) by declaring it as class member.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Collections.ArrayList arrayList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

    // code if any...

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            arrayList.Add(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store values to an **`ArrayList`**. Below is the code for the same :

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        list.Add(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can use the **`list`** as you like then.

Comment: Hope that you missed this point: `so I can use them in other parts of the programme`

Comment: can you pass this list to function where you want to use the values>

Comment: Why not that `list` be global?

Comment: so you can make it global!

Comment: i want to use this list values as to make comparisons with predefined values .so if the list value matches with any of the predefined values execute the desired statements.

Comment: @ubaidashraf: care to make it as a proper answer, properly format the code. then ask for acceptance

Comment: sure@un-lucky. Will do the same

Answer (score 0):

Extending to the code you wrote

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<object> list= new List<object>();
    foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        list.Add(item.ToString());
    }
    // Assign List to Element to display
    //e.g Listbox
    //Listbox1 lbOx1 = new ListBox();
    //lbOx1.Text= list
}
```